# Mongodb parando de funcionar

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb

Estamos na empresa testando um projeto usando banco de dados MongoDB. O banco está instalado em um servidor Linux(CentOS), com 32GB de RAM, mas vez ou outra o banco de dados `para de funcionar` e precisa ser iniciado novamente.

Alguém que já teve experiência com `MongoDB` e também enfrentou esse problema?

Comment: Quer dizer que para sem mensagem nenhuma?  É um pouco amplo essa questão, você tem mais informações do crash?

Comment: Na última linha do arquivo de log diz: Too many connections open: 4000

Comment: Mas será que isso pode estar fazendo o banco parar?

Comment: Acredito que seja possivel sim, além dos 32GB, a configuração do Mongo foi feita para realmente utilizar todo o recurso? Você esta monitorando para quando cair, consiga saber a situação do sistema e da rede possivelmente? Algo pode estar sobrecarregando e derrubando o banco.

Comment: Comentei uma resposta aqui:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258443/mongodb-mmapv1-ou-wiredtiger