# Mongodb - MMapv1 ou WiredTiger?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Iniciamos um projeto com mongodb, na época testando a engine WiredTiger. Esta engine se mostrou mais interessante devido a compactar bem mais os dados do que a mmapv1. Porém, vez ou outra o mongodb simplesmente caia. Assim, testamos a mmapv1, que apesar de não compactar tanto os dados como a wired, resolveu o problema das quedas: o mongodb não caiu mais.
Assim, acabamos por optar pelo uso da mmapv1 mesmo.

Por curiosidade: quem optou pela engine wiredtiger,

- **não tiveram problemas do mongodb cair com frequência?**
- **Se sim, como resolveram?**

Comment: Mantenho uma instalação do MongoDB (3.4) com WiredTiger faz mais ou menos um ano. Nesse ano as únicas vezes que o banco ficou fora foram em manutenções programadas do hardware ou manutenções elétricas (a infra é própria). 

Você chegou a investigar mais a fundo os logs do banco para verificar a causa da queda? Que versão você usou?

Comment: Jorge, na época a versão que testamos do mongo era a 3.4.2. E quanto a verificar log, ele não gravava nada em log ao parar. O serviço simplesmente caia.
Por curiosidade, qual sistema de arquivos você usa no SO: Ext4 ou XFS ?

Comment: É Ext4. Não perguntei do log por ele escrever alguma coisa no momento da parada, e sim antes disso, quantas conexões estavam abertas antes do banco cair? você tinha muita escrita? muita leitura? ele estava usando muito processador? São coisas que podem te indicar o motivo da queda.

Answer (score 0):

Paulo, nas versões mais atuais do Mongo DB é utilizada o WiredTiger como stored engine default.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/storage-engines/

O que pode ter acontecido é que o serviço do banco de dados consumiu toda a memória do seu servidor e o próprio O.S. matou a execução do serviço. Para evitar esse tipo de situação, o ideal é trabalhar utilizando Replica Set, o que garantirá alta disponibilidade para o usuário final e permitirá que você dê manuntenção no servidor com problema com mais calma, e ativar a opção de monitoramento do próprio Mongo DB.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/free-monitoring/

Além do passado acima você também pode limitar o uso de memória que o banco de dados utilizará.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/

Um ponto importante a ser verificado é a configuração do mongod.conf.

Há algum tempo passei por uma situação parecida e achei bastante informação sobre nos links que coloquei aqui no post.

Espero ter ajudado.